# TabLayoutPanel align tab to the right

Tags: gwt

I am using a TabLayoutPanel in GWT and I want to have the last tab show up on the right side of the page. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Common idea:

1. set tab container width to "auto" instead of predefined "16384px"
2. set "float: right" css property to last tab
3. move last tab to firts position

   ```
   public void onModuleLoad() {
           .....
           // init TabLayoutPanel 
           .....
           Widget rightTab = tabPanel.getTabWidget(0).getParent();
           DOM.setStyleAttribute(rightTab.getElement(), "float", "right");
           Widget tabBar = rightTab.getParent();
           tabBar.setWidth("auto");
           tabPanel.selectTab(1);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align all tabs to right try this:

```
.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarFirst {
    width: 100%;
}

.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarRest {
    width: 4px;
}

.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarFirst-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me.. :). But I have two tab panels in My Home page. I want the one should be aligned right, but the second should be aligned the default (left). Is this possible, as gwt has its own css elements for each components ?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer - NO.

I drilled down to the source at GWT 2.3 and AFAIK it easier to build your own composite from `TabBar` and `StackLayoutPanel` than start fighting this implementation.

Just to save you an effort it cannot be centered easily too. 
I am sorry it is like this.

it all hardcoded...

```
private static final int BIG_ENOUGH_TO_NOT_WRAP = 16384;
private final FlowPanel tabBar = new FlowPanel(); 
...
tabBar.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(BIG_ENOUGH_TO_NOT_WRAP, Unit.PX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pure **CSS** solution ? It is good practice to separate your code from design.

```
.gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs {
    width: auto!important;
}
.gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab {
    float: right;
}
```

Remember that your tabs will come in reverse order (first added will be first on the right)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible and will be very easy if you create your own tab.Just create an png image of tab shape (which is having rounded corner at top).Write one css rule.Take one FlextTable and apply that css to each cell that will be your tabs and then add that FlexTable into another mainTable. So in your mainTable in first row there will be tabFlexTable and in second row whatever you want to display after selecting particular tab.So for the first row apply horizontal alignment to right. This the way and same way I am also using in my professional projects.